# Codeigniter MY_Model class

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, model

I'm trying to write my own MY_Model base class but I'm facing a weird problem:

**/core/MY_Model.php**

```
    function __construct() {
        if ( !empty($this->table)) {
            // query db, etc.
        }
        else {
            // even though that I set $this->table value 
            // in the child class, I always ended up here
            // it's always empty!!!!
            log_message('error', 'some error message');
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

**/models/test_model.php**

```
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // ...

}
```

even though that I set $this->table value in the child class, I always ended up finding $table value empty in MY_Model class, it's always empty!!!! any hint please?!

Comment: As far as I see you try to override property `$table`, right? I'm asking just to make clear if I understand your question well.

Comment: PLB: Not exactly, I'm trying to pass table name to the parent class to make it query database for some results. I thought redefining `$table` property in child class will do that. But it's not updating parent class $table property.  

If do a `var_dump()` in parent constructor $table property is still empty.  

thank u.

Comment: That's weird, I do the exact same thing in my MY_Model but $table is set as it should in the parent class...

Comment: @Stephanie strange. I've even tested your script, because it should be working and it really does what you expect.

Comment: weireddddddddddd! thank you so much anyway ;)

Comment: do you call the CI_Model constructor in your MY_model one ?

Comment: @StephanieLuther You're welcome. Let me know if you've solved problem. I'm interested what was causing that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you need something specific/special - you should just use Jamie Rumbelows "MY_Model" - it will probably be better than anything you could write (or me) - and allows you to focus writing other code. No need to re-invent the wheel.

You can get the code from [GitHub here](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model)

[And here is an awesome tutorial](http://www.codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/01/using-jamie-rumbelows-my_model) that shows you how to use the MY_Model in your application.

Honestly - give it a go - you wont regret it.

Answer (score 2):

In your model constructor, do this:

```
class Test_model extends MY_Model{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->table = 'test_model';
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to override the $table variable in the child class. What you're doing is:

- CI_MODEL contains:

  - protected $table, of own scope.
- MY_Model contains:

  - protected $table, of own scope. This overrides the inherited variable $table.

When you override it in the child class, it won't bubble up to the parent class, cause the $table will become a part of the child class only.

What you need to do is remove the declaration of the $table variable in the child:

```
/models/test_model.php
<?php
class Test_model extends MY_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'test_models';
    }

    // ...

}
```